# Get BigQuery metadata when performing query (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery, metadata

When performing a query against BigQuery, it outputs useful info in logs, but the return value is simply the query payload. Is there any way to programmatically get the query metadata in addition to the query result?

Example:

```
bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(…)
result = bigquery.query(sql)
```

Debug-level logs will show something like:

```
@total_bytes_processed=102412,                        
@total_rows=12915
```

I'm wondering how that could be accessed programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the specifics of Ruby (I don't use that language), but when you submit your query, you'll get back a "job id". Use this id to retrieve the meta information about the job/query using the Job API.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource

Comment: Ah that was it. I thought the result was a plain old data structure, but it's actually a QueryData instance (http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-cloud-bigquery/0.20.1/Google/Cloud/Bigquery/QueryData)

Comment: result.job.statistics['totalBytesProcessed'] ✅